# I need a excel formula that will move data from one sheet to another if two different characteristics are met

Tags: excel

So on the attached sheet you can see table 1 and table 2.

[image]

Table 2 will be on a separate worksheet from table 1.I need a formula the will copy columns A,B,F and H over to the other worksheet into table 2 if column H is greater then 0 and column F is HW1,HW3,HW6,HW10 or final.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Don't really know where to start. I guess I should have mentioned that I am new to excel and have been self teaching trying to learn this. I have tried if formulas and match formulas but i can't get anything to work. Unfortunately it seems like you have to be an expert to ask a question on this site.

Comment: *I need a formula* Bad start. Please, post whay you've tried and show some effort.

Comment: If you don't want to help you don't have to. Not sure why this is a bad start if your new to excel and trying to learn some stuff. It's hard to show a whole lot of effort when you don't really know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

If one has the dynamic array formula FILTER():

```
=FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},A:A,B:B,F:F,H:H),(H:H>0)*((F:F="HW1")+(F:F="HW3")+(F:F="HW6")+(F:F="HW10")+(F:F="Final")))
```

Comment: I will try this and see if i can get it to work. This is the first real spreadsheet that i have built. I am a newb at excel but doing my best to learn it as i go.

Comment: this will only work if you have an office 365 subscription.  Otherwise I would recommend the use of vba.

Comment: Thank you scott but this company only has excel 2016 so It won't work but i do appreciate you trying.

Comment: VBA is like Japanese to me I am trying to figure out the regular excel functions LOL. Any help you could provide i would greatly appreciate.